# How to find the last child in lodash map object?

Tags: javascript, react-native, lodash

I looping the array of lists by lodash map function and I've try to remove the Image on last child. But I couldn't find solution.

```
 const menus =[
    {
        name: 'Home',
        key:'dashboard'
    },
    {
        name:'change your pin',
        key:'resetpin'
    },
    {
        name:'Contact',
        key:'contact'
    },
    {
        name:'Sign Out',
        key:'signout'
    }
]
const menuList = map(menus, (el, i) => {
        return <Main>                     
            <Row>
                <Text />
                <Image />
            </Row>
        </Main>
})
```

I don't want the image on last loop

Comment: your second parameter `i` is the index, so check if its equal to `menu.length-1`, bye the way if you want to remove something `map` is not the right choice

Comment: Actually the last child's Image only need to be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the last child's Image only need to be removed. So I achieved by this code.

```
const menuLength = menus.length;
const menuList = map(menus, (el, i) => {
if (menuLength === i + 1) {
        return <Main>                     
            <Row>
                <Text />
            </Row>
        </Main>
}else {
return <Main>                     
            <Row>
                <Text />
                <Image />
            </Row>
        </Main>
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`map()` receives 2 params `value` and `index`, so you can check if your array index is the last in your map function, something like `arr.map((item, index) => index === arr.length-1 && arr.splice(index, 1))`

But if you only want to remove the last item, you can do something like this `arr.splice(-1,1)`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

`_.dropRight(array, [n=1])` from lodash creates a slice of array with n elements dropped from the end. So in your case it would be just `_.dropRight(menus)`. You can do it inside `map` function as well:

```
const menuList = map(_.dropRight(menus), (el, i) => {
    return <Main>                     
        <Row>
            <Text />
            <Image />
        </Row>
    </Main>
})
```

Comment: Actually the last child's Image only need to be removed

Comment: Yes you're right, I didn't quite follow your question. Still you could improve your code by doing
`return <Main>                     
            <Row>
                <Text />
                {menuLength !== i + 1 ? <Image /> : null}
            </Row>
        </Main>
}) ` and have only one return statement. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

why not just do slice? `map(menus.slice(0, -1), (el, i) => ...`)

Comment: yet better `menus.slice(0, -1).map()`